# How to know what tags are valid?

Tags: discussion, tags

How do I know what tags should and should not be used on this site?  I know you discuss a few here in meta, but what makes that official?  I have re-tagged two posts in the last week to only see issues with using those tags.

If it's preferred and easier that I don't retag anything then I can do that too.  I'm not trying to make more work for others (as it appears it must, since it was pointed it out).

Answer (score 3):

The tags that should not be used should all have a description stating that in the tag description that appears when you are typing the tag. Examples include [stci-career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stci-career),  [software-engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering) and [software-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development). There are others, but I don't know what they all are off the top of my head.

You can also follow the [Structured Tag Clean-Up Initiative](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stci) here on Meta if you are interested in helping to clean up the bad tags that exist.